# sprite going of a screen - scrolling background

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

I am trying to get a scrolling background, where when the player goes of the screen the background re-draws and it looks like there is a continuous forever movement, however I can only get a re-draw of the background.

Heres my code:

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((400,200),0,32)

b1 = "resources/images/bac.jpg"
back = pygame.image.load(b1).convert()
image = pygame.image.load("resources/images/badguy.png")
back2 = pygame.image.load(b1).convert()
x = 0
screenWidth = 600
spritex=0
spritey=0
while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    screen.blit(back, (x,0))
    screen.blit(back2,(x-screenWidth,0))
    screen.blit(image, (spritex,spritey))

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    keys_pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys_pressed[K_LEFT]:
        spritex -= 5

    if keys_pressed[K_RIGHT]:
        spritex += 5

    if keys_pressed[K_UP]:
        spritey -= 5

    if keys_pressed[K_DOWN]:
        spritey += 5

    x = x + 1
    if x == screenWidth:
        if spritex > screenWidth or spritey > 200:
            x = 0
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(30)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: so are you trying to make the player sprite stationary in the middle of the screen while your background moves?

Comment: no im trying to move the background as the player moves.

Comment: what is the problem with the above code? Does the background not move?

Comment: the background moves, but when the player goes of screen a new background isnt drawn. I want the screen to move with the player like this : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kntdbhoBUjU

Answer (score 0):

I have found a few mistakes in your code.

- You have 2 event loops doing the same thing.
- screenWidth is set to 600, while your screen width is 400.
- if you want to copy a surface you can do `surface.copy()` instead of loading an image again

Onto the actual question:

What you code does now (after fixing the above):

The background switches gradually without player movement.

To solve this you could use the players position to determine where to draw both your backgrounds. So your drawing code would change to this:

```
screen.blit(back, (spritex,0))
screen.blit(back2,(spritex-screenWidth,0))
screen.blit(image, (spritex,spritey))
```

The link that you have posted does not have a moving background. It works by drawing different sprites at different positions according to where the camera is placed.
The camera center is always at the last farthest position of the player.

EDIT:

As for the camera, it is a bit complicated. The whole point is to separate what is displayed on the screen from actual game logic. A camera object really only need the rect that it encompases, so that it can draw all the objects in its view. It's that simple.

You would also need a way to translate the game coordinates, to the screen ones. This is where the camera comes in.

Comment: so how would i make the camera moevement then?